# When clicking on a link in HTML, it reorganizes my page and only works after 3rd click

Tags: html, css

I can't post whole HTML code because it is way too huge

I have a line that goes like this `<a href="linkblablabla">Link</a>`

When I open the page, there is that link. I click on it once, and my page goes crazy and all elements get reorganized. I click again, they get reorganized again randomly. Now when I click it for the 3rd time it does work. How to stop it reorganizing my page twice and make it work from the start ?

Also , if it means anything, the link is inside a `<td>` tag and inside a table. Table is styled in a different .css file .

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Comment: please add your code here https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the page's url

Comment: First of all, it seems you need to use JavaScript to add some "features" and fix it.
But you don't have to use it. It would be overcomplicated and could be fixed in a simple way. HTML, CSS are not responsible for the advanced functionality. 

Secondly, read about "css class inheritance" because each class can use many styles and make such reorganised elements.
Main class - body, it has subclass of table, table has a subclass of text... it means text style would use style classes of table and body ... table class will use the body style class. I hope it will help a bit.